# Using Google Sheet Formula IMPORTXML to extract hyperlinks from table on web page, and flag when an image is in seperate column

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm doing some analysis which requires me to save table data and (hyperlinked) links to lots of PDF's from a webpage (https://www.asx.com.au/asx/v2/statistics/prevBusDayAnns.do).

I've been playing around with the `=IMPORTHTML` and `=IMPORTXML` formulas in Google Sheets and have managed to extract the table data using `=IMPORTHTML(A1,"table",1)`, but I'm struggling to extract the "Price sens." column which contains images or the hyperlinks attached to the "Headline" items. I'm having no luck with `IMPORTXML` so far, and can't seem to find any solutions online.

[image]

[image]

Comment: whats the url??

Comment: You would need to surround the INDEX() function around the IMPORTHTML() function. IMPORTXML() may also work as long as the site does not use javascript to generate the page. If you provide the URL and specific information you are looking for I would be glad to see if I can give you a specific answer.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, and sorry about omitting the link! I made an edit after posting and must have accidentally deleted it. I also included screenshots, but it doesn't look like they're loading eep. Stackoverflow rookie over here haha. @JohnA and Player0

Answer (score 1):

The formula for `IMPORTXML` you're looking for is:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.asx.com.au/asx/v2/statistics/prevBusDayAnns.do","//*[@id='content']/div/announcement_data/table/tbody/tr")
```

You need to provide an XPATH, which you can get by clicking on an element in the browser dev tools and selecting `copy > XPATH`.

Unfortunately, while this does produce output, it's just the same as for `IMPORTHTML`. The price sensitivity column is always empty, too.

The reason for this is, that the content of the price sensitivity columns is not text, but an image, as you can see in your screenshots.

So it looks like you need some more powerful HTML parsing tools here than Google Sheets provides. It would be easy to look for img tags if you parsed the website using Python and Beautifulsoup, for instance. So you may want to go down this route.

Here's what I got using `IMPORTXML`, same as you:

[image]

The problem is that price sensitivity is img not text:

[image]